# Outlook Addin ExecuteFunction ribbon button does not complete in Outlook for Windows

Tags: outlook-web-addins

When executing a dialog with the dialogApi with an executeFunction ribbon button, the executeFunction event never completes in Outlook for Windows. 
In the manifest we call function "x" that triggers the dialog and adds the event handlers.

```
function x(evt) { _event = evt; ...}
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(settings, function (asyncResult) {
_dialog = asyncResult.dialog;
_dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);
_dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventHandler);
})
function messageHandler() { _event.completed(); }
function eventHandler() { _event.completed(); }
```

[ExecuteFunction loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5gqC.png)

Update:
1. In the manifest, there is a ribbon button definition that executes a function. The function accepts an event parameter passed from the ribbon button click and calls the Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync api to open a dialog. The event parameter is save to a global variable so that it can be called later in the dialog event handlers. When clicking on the ribbon button, the dialog opens normally, however, when the dialog is closed, event.completed does not seem to get called. The attached image runs for about 10-15 minutes.
2. Code snippet is attached from the original posting.
3. Platform used is Outlook 2016 on Windows 10 with IE 11 and Edge
* Strange behavior: for debugging purposes, an arbitrary asynchronous request was being triggered on each of the event handlers. When the request is made before event.completed is called, the event gets completed successfully.

Comment: Hi jchoi76! Thanks for your post. Could you please add more info so we could understand your issue better:
1) can you describe exact steps you do to reproduce the issue?
2) can you share the code that you run inside the dialog page?
3) what versions of Windows, Internet Explorer and Desktop Outlook you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code and it works:

```
var globalEvent;

function eventHandler()
{
  globalEvent.completed(true); 
}

function dialogCallback(asyncResult) 
{
  _dialog = asyncResult.value; 
  _dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventHandler);
}

function ExecuteFunctionMailRead1(event)
{
   globalEvent = event;
   Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("http://contoso.com/", {height: 30, width: 20}, dialogCallback);
}
```

I think the problem is that you need to do: 
_dialog = asyncResult.value; 
instead of
_dialog = asyncResult.**dialog**;